# Argument 2 passed to PHPUnit_Framework_ExpectationFailedException::__construct() must be an instance of PHPUnit_Framework_ComparisonFailure

Tags: selenium, phpunit, fatal-error

I get this error when I run phpunit with selenium.

When I check the class `PHPUnit_Framework_ExpectationFailedException`, I found the following line :

```
public function __construct($message, PHPUnit_Framework_ComparisonFailure $comparisonFailure = NULL)
```

Indeed, the second parameter has to be an object and not a string but if I check the class `SeleniumTestCase`, I can see :

```
    if ($e instanceof PHPUnit_Framework_ExpectationFailedException) {
        if (is_object($e->getComparisonFailure())) {
            $message = $e->getComparisonFailure()->toString();
        } else {
            $message = $e->getMessage();
        }

        $buffer .= "\n" . $message;

        throw new PHPUnit_Framework_ExpectationFailedException($buffer, $message);
```

The `$message` seems to be a string and not an object.

Can you help me ?

**PS:** I am using the version of phpunit (3.6.4) and the last version of selenium (1.1.1)

Answer (score 1):

In PHPUnit 3.6 `PHPUnit_Framework_ExpectationFailedException` was changed by removing the second optional custom message. It looks like [phpunit-selenium](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium) hasn't been updated with this change yet. You can [downgrade to PHPUnit 3.5.x](http://dustyreagan.com/downgrade-phpunit-3-6-to-3-5-15/) in the meantime or fix it and submit a pull request.

Answer (score 0):

The bug has been fixed in the master branch and will be rolled out in the release after 1.1.1.
https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium/issues/78